# Rails 4, axlsx, and acts_as_xlsx: How to make each column its own sheet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, axlsx

**Gems**

https://github.com/randym/axlsx

https://github.com/randym/acts_as_xlsx

**Tutorial**

http://axlsx.blog.randym.net/2011/12/axlsx-making-excel-reports-with-ruby-on.html

In the tutorial the Post model is added to an excel sheet with each attribute being a column.  However, for my purposes, I would like each Post to be its own sheet.  I am new to both of these gems and am having trouble making that adjustment.

Has anyone already accomplished this that could share what they did?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [this](http://axlsx.blog.randym.net/2011/12/axlsx-making-excel-reports-with-ruby-on.html) example, you can create a workbook for each column and copy the first sheet of each workbook into a new workbook with all sheets for the model

```
format.xlsx {
  p = Axlsx::Package.new
  wb = p.workbook

  col_1 = Post.to_xlsx({:columns => [:id]})
            :name => "Posts1"

  wb.worksheets[0] = col_1.workbook.worksheets.first

  col_2 = Post.to_xlsx({:columns => [:content]})
            :name => "Posts2"

  wb.worksheets[1] = col_2.workbook.worksheets.first

  begin
    temp = Tempfile.new("posts.xlsx")
    p.serialize temp.path
    send_file temp.path, :filename => "posts.xlsx", :type => "application/xlsx"
  ensure
    temp.close
    temp.unlink
  end
}
```